# TFS 2012 automated build file not found

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

This could be a pre-existing problem, it's just coincidental that we've upgrade to 2012 also.

When our automated builds are running we receive the error:

```
Exception Message: Could not find a part of the path 'ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png'. (type DirectoryNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectory(String path, Boolean recursive)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.DeleteDirectory.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation).
```

Even after removing all occurrences of this file (I looked everywhere), it still appears to be looking for it and not finding it.

Has any one come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to have happened due to the build location being a branch that was then archived (moved to an archive folder)